# Conneting to async socket failed for some reason

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

i'm currently making a software platform for myself. I have both client and server side software. I'm using asynchronous sockets and I'm having some problems  with connecting. This is my connection function.

```
private bool ConnectSocket()
{
    try
    {
        if((this.soket != null) && this.soket.Connected)
        {
            this.soket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            this.soket.Close();
            return false;
        }
        this.soket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        System.Net.IPAddress adresa = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.server_ip);
        IPEndPoint EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(adresa, 0x9de);
        this.soket.Blocking = false;
        AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(this.OnSocketConnect);
        this.soket.BeginConnect(EndPoint, callback, this.soket);
        if(this.soket.Connected) Console.WriteLine("Uspesno je konektovan socket");
        return true;

    }
    catch(SocketException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Dogodila se greska prilikom povezivanja na server");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Even though I'm not connected my server it recognizes(listen) my connection, and there is some kind of connection. Problem is that I can't continue from this point, I can't send any data because I'm getting an exception for not  being connected, also i'm not going  past this if statement.

```
if(this.soket.Connected) Console.WriteLine("Uspesno je konektovan socket");
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish but looking at your try catch in the if statement are you trying to close the connection if there is an existing one already? Here are some simple suggestions I would try.

```
private bool ConnectSocket()
    {
        try
        {                
            this.soket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            System.Net.IPAddress adresa = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.server_ip);
            IPEndPoint EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(adresa, 0x9de);
            this.soket.Blocking = false;
            AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(this.OnSocketConnect);
            this.soket.BeginConnect(EndPoint, callback, this.soket);
            if(this.soket.Connected) Console.WriteLine("Uspesno je konektovan socket");
            return true;

        }
        catch(SocketException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Dogodila se greska prilikom povezivanja na server");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The above solution just tries to reset the connection without closing the previous like what appeared to happen in the if statement.

```
private bool ConnectSocket()
        {
            try
            {                
                this.soket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                System.Net.IPAddress adresa = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.server_ip);
                IPEndPoint EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(adresa, 0x9de);
                this.soket.Blocking = false;
                AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(this.OnSocketConnect);
                this.soket.BeginConnect(EndPoint, callback, this.soket);
                if(this.soket.Connected) Console.WriteLine("Uspesno je konektovan socket");
                return true;
                if((this.soket == null) && this.soket.Connected == false)<-- or what ever the evaluation for not connection would be.
                    {
                        this.soket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                        this.soket.Close();
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            catch(SocketException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dogodila se greska prilikom povezivanja na server");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The above soltuion just chanes the != on the if to == null so it will only close if the connection is null, double check to make sure you have all the right IPs etc etc required to make the connection

Hope this helps! If not let me know and I'll remove the answer(I had to use an answer because I can't comment under 50 rep) Cheers!

Comment: I wasn't carefull and i made misstake with logical operator. But even after that i could't fix it. I manage to fix it with [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-an-asynchronous-client-socket)

Comment: Right on, glad you were able to figure it out man! If you figured out a solution be sure to accept my answer or close the thread so it doesn't stay opened after you figured it out. Good luck with your project!